# Autolayout "Update Constraints" button, but, calculate proportion, not constant?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode7, nslayoutconstraint

Short version:

The function of the 'Update Constraints' button is that it calculates/updates the numerical values of an **existing** constraint for you (based on **visual** changes in the storyboard). However, it seems to only calculate/update the '**Constant**' value.  This is not useful in the case of **proportional**-mode constraints.  How to use 'Update Constraints' button to modify the '**Multiplier**' numerical value rather than '**Constant**' numerical value?

---

Example, all constraints are **correctly in place**. You wish to change the height of an item.  Do so visually by dragging...

[image]

use 'Update Constraints'...

[image]

it calculates/updates the new value of "Constant" for you...

[image]

(Note that the opposite function, "Update Frames" is also critical; it moves the visual side to where you have changed the text entry values.)

That's fantastic. But.

## But what if, in fact, the constraint is proportional mode?

so, you want the **Constant** value to remain at zero, and you want it to recalculate the **Multiplier** for you.

(Looking at the example above, it should be changing the multiplier from .075 to say .08123.)

Is there a way to do this?

How to make "Update Constraints" button affect the "Multiplier", rather than the "Constant"?  Is it a key modifier, or??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for elaborating your question.

The answer is NO. "Update constraints" button always modifies the constant values of the constraints. This is supported by the fact `NSLayoutConstaint`'s constant property is [read write](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/constant) but `multiplier` is [readonly](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/multiplier).

Comment: @JoeBlow I never practice this. rather than moving the view and updating constraints , we should update the constraints and then update the view(if not updated).